# Unable to create smooch-Webhook for Https endpoint

Tags: integration, webhooks, smooch

I am trying to create a webhook in smooch app.
Whenever I try to add a target endpoint with https such as:

URL : https://www.api.someurl.com/some/path/messageHook

I receive an Error message "No service found at target url's domain"

But When I do the same without HTTPS

URL : http://www.api.someurl.com/some/path/messageHook

It gets added, although this, still, does not work.

Spoke to the Customer service and they said:

> When you create a Webhook Smooch sends a HEAD request to the root of the >domain to make sure that there is a server present. So if your target is >https://example.com/webhook-url/app-id then Smooch will send a HEAD >request to  https://example.com/ and expect a response with a status code >in the 200, 400, or 500 range, excluding 502.
>
> Moreover, our validation request will fail for self-signed or missing >certificates if the endpoint is HTTPS

For the first part :
my endpoint; https://www.api.someurl.com/ returns the 200 status code

And for the second (Certification) part :
I am using LetsEncrypt to signed certificates and https://www.sslshopper.com/ doesn't spot any issues in it

Comment: What is your actual URL? Can't really tell what's happening here with just placeholders. In general if `curl -I https://www.api.someurl.com/` works, you should be good to go

Comment: my Url is : https://www.api.grandhoteldublin.com/ That's seems to be working

Comment: With `https://api.grandhoteldublin.com` I get the error `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: api.grandhoteldublin.com`. With `https://www.api.grandhoteldublin.com` it works. Have you tried supplying `www.api.grandhoteldublin.com`?

Comment: yes I am trying with www.api.grandhoteldublin.com

Comment: This looks like a bug. Will update with more details in a little while

Comment: Cheers. Is it possible that it is only occurring with LetsEncrypt certificates ?

Comment: It's related to this node.js issue https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/16196

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this was a bug on Smooch's side. A fix has been deployed, you should be able to create webhooks pointing to your domain now